# How to use columns().every() to retrieve columns with filtered elements only

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a DataTable that requires me to retrieve the longest .text() element of each column.  To achieve this, I've implemented the following script.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
     deferRender: true,
     autoWidth: false,
     drawCallback: function () {

         var table = $('#example').DataTable();

          table.columns().every(function () {

               var longestSoFar = -1;
               var longestItem;

               this.nodes().to$().each(function () {

                    var text = $(this).text();
                    if (text.length > longestSoFar) {
                         longestSoFar = text.length;
                         longestItem = this;
                    }
               });

               var longestTD = $(longestItem).html();

               console.log(longestTD);

          });
     }
});
```

This scripts works proper and logs the longest .text() element of each column, but if you filter, it continues to pull from the entire list of rows per column regardless if their visible or not.

---

***Example... "unfiltered"***

**FISH**

1. Trout (visible)
2. Catfish (visible)
3. Coelacanth (visible)

In this scenario, my function returns "Coelacanth", which is proper.

---

***Example... "filtered"***

If I filter this DataTable for "Cat"... only one visible row would be displayed... "Catfish".

**FISH**

1. Trout (hidden)
2. Catfish (visible)
3. Coelacanth (hidden)

---

In this scenario, my function should return "Catfish", but instead it continues to return "Coelacanth".  Is there a way to have this ignore any filtered rows and only pull from the "filtered" items visible on screen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Use appropriate [`selector-modifier`](http://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier) (`{ search: 'applied' }`) to account for current search query, if applicable:

```js
// ... skipped ...

table.columns().every(function (index) {
   var longestSoFar = -1;
   var longestItem;

   var column = table.column(index, { search: 'applied' });
   column.nodes().to$().each(function () {

// ... skipped ...
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s1dpx7t9/) for code and demonstration.

> **NOTES**

There was a issue with jQuery DataTables versions 1.10.6 - 1.10.9 where [`selector-modifier`](http://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier) (`{ search: 'applied' }`) couldn't be used as a parameter to [`columns().every()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns%28%29.every%28%29) API method, see this [issue #679](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/679).

If using nightly build or jQuery DataTables version released after 1.10.9, it is possible to use the code below:

```js
// ... skipped ...

var table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.columns({ search: 'applied' }).every(function (index) {

   this.nodes().to$().each(function () {
   // ... skipped ...
```

Comment: It still returns all results, even those removed from filter.

Comment: Side note for anyone else who happens upon this... DataTables 1.10.9 minimum is needed.

Comment: @kojay, my example uses 1.10.9 but `columns().every()` is available since 1.10.6. One could even use [`each()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/each%28%29) which is available since 1.10.0.

Comment: i fully agree with you on this.  However, using your above script and 1.10.6 has a weird replication issue.  It pulls the longest element of the 1st column and logs it for each column in the table.  When i checked my current version number of DT, i was using 1.10.6 and noticed you used 1.10.9, so i upgraded my version and it worked as you outlined.

I just don't want anyone else trying to replicate it, receive false results because your script was flawless in every respect.